# Email verification link using localhost in a production environment

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-6

I have a Laravel 6.7.0 app deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

The environment variables are set using Elastic Beanstalk config files (not .env file).

I have set the env variables to production including the APP_URL. The env('APP_URL') and the config('app.url') are returning the correct value (which is my live domain name) except for the email verification link which is returning localhost. The APP_URL is working fine in all other emails including the password reset email.

I tried cache:clear and config:clear on the server but still no luck. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should run

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

if you are running queues for sending e-mails

Answer (score 0):

Your Email verification link display  local host on production because url is  wrong change  url to {{url('/verificationlink')}}